# Multiple $_GET Functions don't work

Tags: php, html, get

I have been designing a few websites. i have been trying to use multiple if(isset($_GET['type']) == 'page') { } and so forth functions. they seem not be be working can someone enlighten me?

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['type']) == 'all') {
    // View All Pages Title
    echo '<h3>View All Pages</h3>';

        if($control1 == 'all') {
            echo '<table width="100%" border="0">';
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<th scope="col">Page Name</th>';
            echo '<th scope="col">Time Created</th>';
            echo '<th scope="col">View</th>';
            echo '<th scope="col">Edit</th>';
            echo '<th scope="col">Delete</th>';
            echo '</tr>';                 
            $qry=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM page", $con);
            if(!$qry) {
                die("Query Failed: ". mysql_error());
        }
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($qry)) {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td height="38">'.$row['page_title'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$row['page_updated'].'</td>';
            echo '<td><a href="page.php?view=page&page='.$row['page_link'].'">View</a></td>';
            echo '<td><a href="page.php?edit='.$row['page_link'].'">Edit</td>';
            echo '<td><a href="page.php?delete='.$row['id'].'">Delete</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }     
        echo '</table>';
    }
    else {
        echo "<p>You can't view all the pages. Your Account does not hold the correct priorirty</p>";   
    }
}
elseif(isset($_GET['type']) == 'add') {
    // Add New Page Title
    echo '<h3>Add New Page</h3>';
        if($control1 == 'all') {
            echo '<p><a href="pages.php?type=add&add=control" target="new">Click Here to add a new page</a></p>';
    }
    else {
        echo "<p>You can't add new pages. Your Account does not hold the correct priority.</p>";
    }
}
elseif(isset($_GET['type']) == 'edit') {
    // Edit Pages Title
    echo '<h3>Edit a Page</h3>';
        if($control1 == 'all') {
            echo '<table width="100%" border="0">';
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<th scope="col">Page Name</th>';
            echo '<th scope="col">Edit</th>';
            echo '</tr>';
            $qry=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM page", $con);
                if(!$qry) {
                    die("Query Failed: ". mysql_error());
            }
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($qry)) {
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td height="38">'.$row['page_title'].'</td>';
                echo '<td><a href="page.php?edit='.$row['page_link'].'">Edit</td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            }
            echo '</table>';
        }
        else {
            echo "<p>You can't edit any pages. Your Account does not hold the correct priority </p>";
        }
    }
?>
```

This is the exact code. If you can explain what it is I can do to fix it, it would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isset($_GET['type'])` returns a boolean value, so if you compare that boolean with anything that is not the same boolean ( `isset($_GET['type']) == 'all'` ) it will return false.

You should do

```
if ( isset($_GET['type']) && $_GET['type'] == 'all' ) { // code }
```

Comment: Thanks, I never realized. So i should do this with all my $_GET functions?

Answer (score 0):

Must be like this

```
if(isset($_GET['type']) && $_GET['type'] == 'page')
```

Answer (score 0):

`isset` return boolean: true or false. Therefore your code:

```
if(isset($_GET['type']) == 'page')
```

won't work. You can change it like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['type']) and $_GET['type'] == 'page')
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `isset()` function returns only `TRUE` or `FALSE` and you are comparing it to string. Just use it that way:

```
if (isset($_GET['type']) {
   if ($_GET['type'] == 'page') {
      //...
   } elseif($_GET['type'] == 'add') {
      //and so on...
   }
}
```

It's better to put `isset` test at the beginning so you won't check it in every `if` statement.

Comment: Everyone else said todo this: if(isset($_GET['type']) and $_GET['type'] == 'page') So I'm not sure if your answer is right?

Comment: Yes, it is right:) It makes no sense to check `$_GET['type'] == 'add'` if `$_GET['type']` is not set. But if you will check it in every `if` statement, you will repeat yourself, but you really don't need to, you can check if `$_GET` is set only once. Try it and it will work for sure.

Comment: thanks Peter, i did and it kinda worked, i might not have implemented it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, isset() is returning a boolean (true/false) which you are comparing with "all", "add" and so on. That is not what you want.

you could do:

```
if (isset($_GET['type']) && $_GET['type'] == "all") {
    #your code here
}
```